# What function does the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ converge to in its disc of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis

For the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$, its radius of convergence is 1 which implies that this series is absolutely convergent in the the unit ball $\{z:|z|<1\}$.

Since it is absolutely convergent in $\{z:|z|<1\}$, I want to ask what exact function does this series converge to?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5En%2Fn%5E2

Comment: We denote the resulting function (and its analytic continuation to $\Bbb{C}\setminus[1,\infty)$) as $\operatorname{Li}(z)$, the dilogarithm. Also, the sum should begin with $n=1$ to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Thank you, it is my first time to meet this kind of function, $Li(z)$. It seems very useful to use Wolframalpha to compute the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you start the sum at $n=1$ (otherwise your first term involves division by zero), this is one of the [polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).  $$  \mathrm{Li}_s(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^s}  $$

So in particular, you have asked about $\mathrm{Li}_2(z)$, also known as the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm).  See also the [Dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) page at MathWorld and [Dilogarithms](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#i) at the NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions.